# How can I connect my iPhone to an office network that has no WiFi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, iphone, wifi-configuration

My office does not have a WiFi network, yet I need to connect my iPhone to the network to test some stuff.

Can I buy some type of an access point that I can plug into my laptop and then have my iPhone connect to that?  Would something like that even work?

Any other suggestions?

P.S. I have no access to the office router.

Comment: If you need it for work, talk to your IT department about getting a wireless access point installed. Your IT group should be able to get you what you need to do your job.
Alternatively, there might be a hacky way to do it that shouldn't upset your IT group (http://lifehacker.com/hack-together-a-way-to-connect-an-ipad-or-iphone-over-e-1770270331). I've never tried it, so I have no idea if it'll work.

Comment: "My office does not have a WiFi network, yet I need to connect my iPhone to the network to test some stuff." - This means what you want isn't possible. iPhone can only access a network through a wireless connection.

Comment: @Ramhound Via a Lightning USB dongle connected to a USB Ethernet dongle, iPhones and iPads can do wired Ethernet. That's a solution for OP without requiring an AP.

Answer (score 1):

Asuming that you have a Windows laptop you can use a virtual wifi router like [mHotspot](http://www.mhotspot.com), a free software, that allows you and creates a secure wifi hotspot. You can share single internet connection(LAN, Ethernet, Data-Card, 3G/4G, Wifi) for multiple devices like Laptops, iPhones, Android phones, PDAs, iPads etc.
(Note: It's free but marked as Bundleware: The installer contains Opencandy. If you want to install it, DECLINE all the other softwares in all the steps of the downloader.)

There are other options like [Connectivity Hotspot](http://www.connectify.me/) (Freemium) or [Virtual Router Plus](https://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualrouterpl/) (OpenSource, maybe flagged as malware but it's okay - but double checking never hurts) too.

For macOS I believe there is only [Tanaza](https://www.tanaza.com/).

In any event, as pointed out by others, double check if you are in line with your company's policies in advance.

Comment: opening up the office network with a wireless signal, even if it is secured in some way, may violate company policy - it is usually best not to advise someone to do this without checking with their IT group first.

Comment: Does the IP address assigned with a solution like mHotspot a virtual address generated by the laptop or does it get it from the router?

In other words, would I be able to ping my iPhone from a PC on the network with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have your IT department put up a $100 wireless access point, or get one yourself and do it with their blessing.  It's very sneaky to install unauthorized network equipment.  If someone outside breaks in, torrents some movies, or does some outright illegal because there was a handy wireless network, then it's on you.